# Eclipse direct shortcut instead of yellow popup?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

How do I remove this middle step of having to press enter after F12 to make the actual navigation? I don't need this yellow popup telling me there's one shortcut for me.

[image]

[image]

In the second image you can see the problem: I want F12 to immediate open up the definition / declaration of the symbol my cursor is currently at. Need it for Java.

Comment: Have you tried removing the other F12 bindings? You should only keep the last one I guess.

Comment: Clicking on an object and pressing the 'F3" key will take you to the declaration. It is actually shortcut to "Open declaration"

Comment: user, I removed the other f12 bindings, but now it doesn't work at all. Not exactly easy to find out which setting is the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed multiple bindings for the same key.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to hover over the type/method with your mouse then hold ctrl and left mouse click.

It's a default shortcut in eclipse.

edit: sorry this should have been a comment to your question, not an answer.